# Open cursor for dynamic table name in PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create procedure, that will use cursor, which is the same for arbitrary tables. My current one looks like this:

```
create or replace
  PROCEDURE
    some_name(
      p_talbe_name IN VARCHAR2,
      p_chunk_size IN NUMBER,
      p_row_limit IN NUMBER
    ) AS

  CURSOR v_cur IS
     SELECT common_column,
       ora_hash(substr(common_column, 1, 15), p_chunk_size) as chunk_number
     -- Here it can find the table!
     FROM p_table_name;

  TYPE t_sample IS TALBE OF v_cur%rowtype;
  v_sample t_sample;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cur;
  LOOP FETCH v_cur BULK COLLECT INTO v_sample LIMIT p_row_limit;
    FORALL i IN v_sample.first .. v_sample.last
    INSERT INTO chunks VALUES v_sample(i);
    COMMIT;
    EXIT WHEN v_cur%notfound;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE v_cur;
END;
```

The problem is that it cannot find the table named `p_table_name` which I want to parametrize. The thing is that I need to create chunks based on hashes for `common_column` which exists in all intended tables. How to deal with that problem? Maybe there is the equivalent oracle code that will do the same thing? Then I need the same efficiency for the query. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you looping through and pulling the data into an array before inserting it into a table, rather than just doing a dynamic insert-as-select? Is this some sort of homework where you are artificially constrained in the way you can achieve your aim, or is there some other reason?

Comment: @Boneist no, I do not have any constrains on the solution. I just need an efficient one. This code is actually part of bigger sql which I'm trying to refactor by extracting the re-usable procedures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this as a single insert-as-select statement, complicated only by the fact you're passing in the table_name, so we need to use dynamic sql.

I would do it something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE some_name(p_table_name IN VARCHAR2,
                                      p_chunk_size IN NUMBER,
                                      p_row_limit  IN NUMBER) AS

  v_table_name VARCHAR2(32); -- 30 characters for the tablename, 2 for doublequotes in case of case sensitive names, e.g. "table_name"

  v_insert_sql CLOB;
BEGIN
  -- Sanitise the passed in table_name, to ensure it meets the rules for being an identifier name. This is to avoid SQL injection in the dynamic SQL
  -- statement we'll be using later.
  v_table_name := DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL(p_table_name);

  v_insert_sql := 'insert into chunks (common_column_name, chunk_number)'||CHR(10)|| -- replace the column names with the actual names of your chunks table columns.
                  'select common_column,'||CHR(10)||
                  '       ora_hash(substr(common_column, 1, 15), :p_chunk_size) AS chunk_number'||CHR(10)||
                  'from   '||v_table_name||CHR(10)||
                  'where  rownum <= :p_row_limit';

  -- Used for debug purposes, so you can see the definition of the statement that's going to be run.
  -- Remove before putting the code in production / convert to proper logging code:
  dbms_output.put_line(v_insert_sql);

  -- Now run the statement:
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_insert_sql USING p_chunk_size, p_row_limit;

  -- I've included the p_row_limit in the above statement, since I'm not sure if your original code loops through all the rows once it processes the
  -- first p_row_limit rows. If you need to insert all rows from the p_table_name into the chunks table, remove the predicate from the insert sql and the extra bind variable passed into the execute immediate.
END some_name;
/
```

By using a single insert-as-select statement, you are using the most efficient way of doing the work. Doing the bulk collect (which you were using) would use up memory (storing the data in the array) and cause extra context switches between the PL/SQL and SQL engines that the insert-as-select statement avoids.

Comment: Are you sure that this `insert into` statement will behave the same way as cursor with `bulk insert`?

Comment: Pretty sure, but it's up to you to test it, since you didn't provide a full test case for us to play with. N.B. I may have read your original code wrong; you may be looping through all the rows, in which case you wouldn't need the predicate in the dynamic insert-as-select, nor the p_row_limit parameter.

Comment: I've only come across it in the past 2 or 3 years; I think it's pretty nifty *{:-)

Comment: @Boneist I found out that we need the row_limit, because we got out of `UNDO` space. That's why the cursor with limit was necessary. Do you think we have other options to consider?

Comment: Is this something that is run regularly? If so, I would highly recommend getting the undo tablespace resized accordingly, rather than trying to work around it.